# Change MySQL default installation directory in OS X

Tags: mysql-5.6, mac-os-x

I install mysql in default installation directory `/usr/local/mysql`

Is it possible to change mysql installation directory to another path?

I am running OS X 10.10 & MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Open `mysqld_safe` in `NewMysqlDir/bin` with a text editor & replase all `/usr/local/mysql` to `NewMysqlDir` & save.

2- Open `mysqld_safe` in `NewMysqlDir/bin` with Terminal